# Half of an image above other image in xamarin forms

Tags: xaml, layout, xamarin.forms

I am working with xamarin forms 
And I need to create a layout with two objects positionated like that:

[image]

half of one(circle) above the other object(square)

I have searched and it seem I need to use relative layout...
I tried to do that setting the both objects in the same grid (row and line 0), and then, using constraintX to set the second in the same Y with factor 0 and a negative constant...But it didn't work. The a deleted the lines and can't show here, unfortunately...the only thing that happend in this is: the both was in the same position in y, but I could do like the image above...
Can someone help me with an example, idea or anything? thank you very much!

My code now - the rodape image is the square and the reload is the circle
I now the fact that the reload is under the square is wrong, but, for now, it is pretend the visual...an it gives me a result close that I want...but not exactly

```
<!--Rodapé Grid-->
<RelativeLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
                VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand" 
                BackgroundColor="Black">
    <Grid BackgroundColor="Red"
           RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,
                                                                 Property=Width,
                                                                 Factor=1,
                                                                 Constant=0}">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Image Source="rodape.png" 
               Aspect="Fill"
               HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
               Grid.Row="0"
               Grid.Column="0">
            <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="FranqueadoOnTapGestureRecognizerTapped"/>
            </Image.GestureRecognizers>
        </Image>
        <!--Escrito Rodapé-->
        <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical"
                     VerticalOptions="End"
                     HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                     Grid.Row="0"
                     Spacing="0"
                     Grid.Column="0">
            <Image Source="reloadicon.png"/>
            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" 
                         HorizontalOptions="Center">
                <local:MyLabel NamedFontSize="Medium" 
                               FontSizeFactor="0.7" 
                               Text="Seja um Franqueado:"
                               TextColor="White"
                               FontAttributes="Bold"
                               Style="{StaticResource labelsfont}"/>
                <local:MyLabel NamedFontSize="Medium" 
                               FontSizeFactor="0.7" Text="montanaexpress.com"
                               Style="{StaticResource labelsfont}"
                               TextColor="{StaticResource laranjacolor}"/>              
            </StackLayout>
        </StackLayout>
    </Grid>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Not 100% sure what ask here is but if you need to draw a circle over a square this is a good option for a custom control where you draw directly to native canvases

Answer (score 6):

Try something like this, I think it's simpler:

```
<Grid>
    <BoxView Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1"
             Color="Red"
             HeightRequest="20"
             HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>
    <Frame Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2"
           BackgroundColor="Yellow"
           HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
           VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
           WidthRequest="40"
           HeightRequest="40"
           CornerRadius="40"
           Margin="0,5,0,10"/>
</Grid>
```

What you'll get:
[image]

**EDIT:**

As you've required at comments, using your images you should do something like this:

```
<Grid>   
    <Image Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0"
           Source="rodape.png" 
           Aspect="Fill"
           HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
        <Image.GestureRecognizers>
            <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="FranqueadoOnTapGestureRecognizerTapped"/>
        </Image.GestureRecognizers>
    </Image>               
    <Image Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2"
           Source="reloadicon.png"
           HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
           VerticalOptions="Center"/>
</Grid>
```

*Note: I'm not able to figure out how the labels and the image should be displayed in your layout. You have to add it manually*

Comment: But, when I use height and width request I set a static size to my view, don't I?

Comment: Yes, I've used it to realize your visual model. You must to change the BoxView and Frame elements to your images. Foget about the fixed sizes and use the positional attributes like Horizontal and VerticalOptions, Grid.Column, Row and RowSpan. Tell me if it works as you want with your images